# BibLaTeX-dw style authortitle-dw: How to apply firstfull=true but not to entries with shorthand field

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-dw

I'm using BibLaTeX with `style=authortitle-dw` and option `firstfull=true`. Is there a way to NOT apply `firstfull=true` to those entries in my .bib-file, which have a `shorthand` entry?

A MWE, that only shows, that `firstfull=true` works as expected, would be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,backend=biber, firstfull=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Book{A1,
  Title                    = {Title1},
  Author                   = {AuthorA},
  Year                     = {1900},
  Shorthand                = {GuI}
}

@Book{B2,
  Title                    = {Title2},
  Author                   = {AuthorB},
  Year                     = {1900}
}

@Book{C2,
  Title                    = {Title2},
  Author                   = {AuthorC},
  Year                     = {1900}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

"Some citation of a shorthand title"\parencite[][34]{A1}

"Some citation of the same shorthand title in a footnote"\footcite[][34]{A1}

"Some citation of the same title from another page"\footcite[][70]{A1}

"Some citation of a non-shorthand title"\footcite[][12]{B2}

"Some citation of the same non-shorthand title from another page"\footcite[][15]{B2}

"Some citation of the same non-shorthand title from another author"\footcite[][15]{C2}

\printshorthands

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked in the `authortitle-dw.cbx` file and might have found a solution. Changing the `\newbibmacro*{cite}` definition seems to get the job done:

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \ifbool{cbx:inreffull}
     {\usebibmacro{cite:inreffull}}
    {\ifbool{cbx:firstfull}
      {\ifciteseen
        {\usebibmacro{cite:normal}}
        {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
           {\usebibmacro{cite:firstfull}}
           {\usebibmacro{cite:normal}}}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:normal}}}}
```

But since I don't really know, what I'm doing, I don't know, if that solution is appropriate for very long documents.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,backend=biber, firstfull=true]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \ifbool{cbx:inreffull}
     {\usebibmacro{cite:inreffull}}
    {\ifbool{cbx:firstfull}
      {\ifciteseen
        {\usebibmacro{cite:normal}}
        {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
           {\usebibmacro{cite:firstfull}}
           {\usebibmacro{cite:normal}}}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:normal}}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Book{A1,
  Title                    = {Title1},
  Author                   = {AuthorA},
  Year                     = {1900},
  Shorthand                = {GuI}
}

@Book{B2,
  Title                    = {Title2},
  Author                   = {AuthorB},
  Year                     = {1900}
}

@Book{C2,
  Title                    = {Title2},
  Author                   = {AuthorC},
  Year                     = {1900}
}
 \end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

"Some citation of a shorthand title"\parencite[][34]{A1}

"Some citation of the same shorthand title in a footnote"\footcite[][34]{A1}

"Some citation of the same title from another page"\footcite[][70]{A1}

"Some citation of a non-shorthand title"\footcite[][12]{B2}

"Some citation of the same non-shorthand title from another page"\footcite[][15]{B2}

"Some citation of the same non-shorthand title from another author"\footcite[][15]{C2}

\printshorthands

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```